# Is this the most efficient way to find leap years in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, while-loop

I began reading Learning to Program, 2nd Edition yesterday. I find it very easy to follow and I'm very muchly so enjoying it. I came to a section where I am challenged with building a Ruby app that will tell me which years are leap years. I would like to know how you think I did on making this app work. It works, and that's good, but is it the most efficient way?

(Leap years are divisible by 4, evenly. So I knew that using modulo, each leap year had to % 4 == 0.)

```
puts "So you want to know which years are leap years?"

puts "What year to begin with?"
ySt = gets.chomp.to_i

puts "What year to end with?"
yEn = gets.chomp.to_i

while ySt <= yEn

if ySt % 4 == 1
    ySt = ySt + 3
elsif ySt % 4 == 2
    ySt = ySt + 2
elsif ySt % 4 == 3
    ySt = ySt + 1
end

puts ySt
ySt = ySt + 4
end
```

This is day 2 for me in Ruby and I'm pretty proud that I made this work, as no help or example is given in the book. I'd just like to see how others would have done it or if you think this is great!

Thank you in advance. When I become more experienced I'll be sure to return the knowledge and favor here on StackOverflow.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Not all years divisible by 4 are leap years, so your code isn't even correct, let alone efficient.

Comment: It's a good effort and kudos for coming up with a working algorithm!
Note that if you do 2013 to 2015 it will print 2016 even though that's out of the range.  As que says, not all yeras divisible by 4 are leap years, but what you have will work fine for 1901 through 2099.

Comment: I'm new to StackOverflow and was not aware that this needed to be posted elsewhere. For that, I apologize. Also, I thought leap year was every four years. Huh, well... I'm glad I just got it to work! Too bad it only worked for my broken knowledge of leap years. -_-

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has a method [`Date::leap?`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-leap-3F):

```
require 'date'

(1980..2000).each do |year|
  puts year if Date.leap?(year)
end
```

Output:

```
1980
1984
1988
1992
1996
2000
```

Comment: I mildly expected there to be more in depth ways to solve this problem, but I only know as far as While-Loops at this point in time and the challenge was to come up with an algorithm based on what had been taught so far in The Pragmatic Programmer's guide. I'm assuming this is a function you have presented me with. (Something I hope to learn very soon.) I thank you for the solution, though!